# Inserting new page in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm having problems inserting a new page in Microsoft Word. My document has a flow chart in it, and the cursor is "stuck" in the top middle of it. If I try to insert a new page it breaks the page there and splits the image up. Is there any way to create a new page disregarding page breaks, or to move the cursor to the bottom?

Comment: Alt + Ctrl + Page Down will move the cursor to the bottom of the current screen of text. But I don't know how to fix your issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but try this:

- remove the flowchart (cut and paste into another document, etc)
- insert a next page section break (insert > break > section breaks > next page in Office XP)
- copy the flowchart back into your original document before the new section break

Comment: Accepting this as answer just because I don't think what I said is possible. I tried what you said earlier and you can't copy the flow chart.

Comment: @Random - that's strange - where is the flowchart from?

Answer (score 0):

First select `Insert blank page`, which will insert a new page above flow chart page.

Open menu option `View -> Outline`

It will show an outline of all pages in your word document.

You can then drag the page containing your flowchart and drag it to any location above of your word document.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread but hopefully this will help somebody.  I was having a similar problem not being able to insert a blank page after I drew a flowchart in **Word 2013**.  To create the next page:

- I selected all the objects I had created on the page and grouped them into one grouping.  You could save time by creating the group when you first start (i.e. canvas)
- Selecting either all the objects (if not grouped) or the single group gives a new menu of Drawing Tools -> Format at the top of the screen.
- With the group selected, click the button labeled Wrap Text and select the option Through.  That will take it out of line with the text.
- At the top of the page, or anywhere in the page for that matter, go to Insert -> New Page.  You should now have a new blank page after your chart.

Answer (score 0):

in word 2007, all i did was go to:

page layout > breaks > selection breaks > next page

then everything in my document was moved to the second page. insert some text to the new page and it will stay when you move everything back up.

bear in mind that my document was entirely made up of images and my text (which was NOT in a text box) stayed on its original page.

hope this helped :P